# implementing single sign-on in a GWT application

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, gwt, single-sign-on

I have an application where the UI is designed on GWT. We wish to implement single sign on (SSO) in our application. The SSO will send an HTTP header containing user information.

Can anybody guide me how to consume this HTTP header and make it available to my GWT application entry point.

I read that we cannot read HTTP headers in javascript hence GWT. But will it be possible to consume it via creating GWT RemoteServiceServlet?

Comment: The SSO service exists and it will be sending a HTTP header to my application. My requirement is consuming the HTTP header in/out of my GWT application and passing this information in my GWT application.

Comment: So it will send it to your applications server? Why do you need the information in your GWT application? Are you going to make direct calls with the connection info from your GWT client ?

Comment: HTTP header will contain the user information which i need to display in my gwt pages.